# connect ECONNREFUSED to WSL2 ubuntu-18.04

Tags: wsl-2

I'm runing my flask project use wsl2 interpreter, and runing my vue project in my windows local, now there is a problem, yhr frontend can not connect backend, like below

```
Proxy error: Could not proxy request /summary_statistics from localhost:9527 to http://172.28.32.1:9999/
```

172.28.32.1 is my wsl2 ip.

anyone can help?

Comment: also I use postman to test my backend  interface, also connect ECONNREFUSED

Answer (score 1):

I have solve the problem, the IP is wrong..., I got from powershell with command

```
ipconfig
```

but I got another ip address in wsl with command

```
ifconfig
```

the true ip address is the second.